# Linked list implementation - prints first element in infinite loop

Tags: java

I am trying to implement linked list and I dont get whats wrong with this code.
Goes into an infinite loop printing 1...the start node is instantiated the first time when insert() is invoked

**Node**

```
public class Node {

    int data;
    Node next;


    public Node(int data, Node next) {
        super();
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }


    public Node() 
    {
        super();
    }

}
```

**LinkedList**

```
public class LinkedList {

    Node start = null;

    void insert(int value)
    {

        Node current;
        current = start;

        if(start == null)
        {
            start = new Node(value, null);
            start.data = value;
            start.next = null;
        }

        else
        {
            while(current.next != null)
            {
                current = current.next;
            }
            current.next = new Node();
            current.next.data = value;
            current.next.next = null;
        }

    }

    void show()
    {
        Node curr = start;
        while(curr.next != null)
        {
            System.out.println(curr.data);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LinkedList ll = new LinkedList();
        ll.insert(1);
        ll.insert(7);
        ll.insert(5);
        ll.insert(3);
        ll.insert(9);

        ll.show();

    }

}
```

Comment: Hint: `curr = curr.next` is missing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you `show()` method like below:

```
void show() {
    Node curr = start;
    while (curr.next != null) {
        System.out.println(curr.data);
        curr = curr.next; // This part was missing.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `curr = curr.next;` in the while loop of

Answer (score 0):

In your `show()` method you are missing the:
`curr = curr.next`

after you are printing the current node's value;